# "Cachebusting" / Obtain latest KMZ from NWS with GMaps API and JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps to display radar and weather alert data from NWS. I have had difficulty displaying the latest polygonal alert data.

I am able to get the latest file by *manually* modifying the query string each time I want to update the KMZ polygons.

How can I include scripting to modify the end string of the KMZ filename within my Google Maps script, so that I obtain a fresh copy of the latest polygonal alert data each time the site is visited?

```
var ctaLayer

ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
 url:'https://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/watch/ActiveWW.kmz?=dummy5',  
 preserveViewport:true, 
 suppressInfoWindows:false, 
 map:map,
 });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force Google to update KML cache on their servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651520/how-to-force-google-to-update-kml-cache-on-their-servers)

Comment: Question answered. I appreciate you helping find this solution.